# Yii working with criteria

Tags: yii, criteria

I have two tables `order` and `order_version`

```
order

|  id |
|  1  |
|  2  |


order_version
| id | order_id | status |
| 1  |     1    |    0   |
| 2  |     2    |    0   |
| 3  |     1    |    1   |
| 4  |     1    |    2   |
```

I want to find all the orders which have changed version. It means I want to get only order with `id='1'`, because another one has not been changed and has only one version.
Tried this one:

```
1)   $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
2)   $criteria->with = array('orderVersions');
3)   $criteria->addCondition("(SELECT MAX(status)  FROM order_version) != '0'");
4)   $criteria->addInCondition('order.id', $orderArray);        
5)   $criteria->order = 'order.id DESC';
6)   $orders = Order::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

`$orderArray` variable is the array of `order` `id`s.
First of all the problem is in the 4th line.

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'order.id' in 'where clause'
```

if I do just `id` instead of `order.id` then I have

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous.
```

The same problem with the 5th line.
Another: I do not really know how to use sub queries in yii, which is the 3rd line.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Yii doesn't care about the original table name, in this case `order`, it cares only about the relation name. The original table is always aliased as `t` and `order_version` in this case is `orderVersions`.

Comment: okay, with aliases it's clear, thanks. What about sub query? Actually if I replace `order_version` with `orderVersions` I have an error `Table 'imdb.orderVersions' doesn't exist`. Maybe it's because of WHERE clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your text I conclude that you want to get all the orders that have a status not equal to 0 (or bigger than zero)? Try this:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria(array(
  'together' => TRUE,
  'with' => array('orderVersions' => array(
  'having' => 'MAX(`orderVersions`.`status`) > 0'
)),
'order' => '`t`.`id` DESC'
));
$criteria->addInCondition('`t`.`id`',$orderArray);
```

If you just want the grouped orders with the highest version possible, but with status higher than 0:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria(array(
  'together' => TRUE,
  'with' => array('orderVersions' => array(
  'having' => 'MAX(`orderVersions`.`status`) > 0'
)),
'order' => 'MAX(`t`.`id`) DESC',
'group' => '`t`.`id`'
));
$criteria->addInCondition('`t`.`id`',$orderArray);
```

Comment: That worked fine, except one thing. `findAll()` returns correct orders, but with the first order_version it met in the table. For example: regarding table description in my question, if I do `MAX(orderVersions.status) = 2` it returns correct only the 1st order, but with the 1st version as well. Is it possible to return the 1st order but with all the versions?

Comment: Yes it is, remove the `'having'` clause, and add a `'limit' => 1` after the 'order' clause, also remove the `'group'` clause. < Incorrect: you will have to return multiple rows if you want all the versions, but if you do I would just use 2 queries, one for getting the required order and another for getting all the versions. Otherwise you will be returning alot of unnecessary data

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `order.id` try `t.id`.

This is because when you are using the `$criteria->with` option you are joining that table to the query, so there will be two `id` fields, one in the `order` table and one in the `order_version` table.

Yii will normally give the main table you are querying (`order` in this case) an alias of `t` and I think will normally give any tables joined by a relation an alias of their relation name.

If you'd like to get the actual alias yii is using you can use [getTableAlias](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#getTableAlias-detail). But I don't think you would be able to use this in your case as you're calling `findAll()` statically. If you're using it within the model context you could call it like so:

```
$alias = $this->getTableAlias();
```

Or like so if you're using in default scope or other places you don't want to run extra checks or quote the alias name;

```
$alias = $this->getTableAlias(false,false);
```

Comment: Okay thanks a lot. But everywhere I call it, I get `t`. I do: `$alias = Order::model()->getTableAlias();`

Comment: getTableAlias() is more useful when you call it from within a model, i.e. not statically like you are calling findAll(), that was just some extra info to try and explain how you can use in other cases. Try just using t.id instead of order.id?